# How do I reduce the heap size of a program to see how it behaves when it runs out of memory?

Tags: c, malloc

I am currently writing a program that allocates memory in various places. I am interested in seeing how my program behaves when the heap runs out of memory, namely when when malloc() returns NULL.

Is there a compiler option that can let me set the heap size to something very small so I can see what happens immediately? I am using the gcc compiler.

Comment: Note that, depending on your OS, you can't necessarily assume that `malloc` will actually return `NULL` when you run out of memory. Instead, there's a good chance that you will successfully obtain virtual memory, and then die as soon as you try to actually use it. There's no safe, portable way to handle running out of memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify stack and heap sizes like this:

```
gcc -Wl,--stack=xxxxx -Wl,--heap=yyyyy ...
```

Comment: This won't work on anything except Windows.

Comment: Going to point out that size has to be in bytes

Answer (score 2):

At least if on Linux you could use `ulimit -m <max mem>` prior to running your program.

Answer (score 1):

Compile as 32 bit and exhaust the virtual address space by reserving large chunks of memory (you don't need to commit - just reserve (these are Windows terms, I'm sure they have Linux equivalents).

Windows also has Job Objects that you can use to limit memory but maybe the simple `VirtualAlloc` technique will work.

The nice thing about it is that you can dynamically change the limit, maybe using a timer, to stress the program again and again at random times.

Answer (score 1):

What about replacing `malloc` & friends with your own code to simulate the condition? I’m not sure about the best way to do it, maybe `LD_PRELOAD` would work ([some example code here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15213-s03/src/interposition/mymalloc.c)).